# fakepath when get file path in javascript code

Tags: javascript, get, filepath

I'm using this javascript code to get the path of a file, but every time when I run the code, the path appears as "C:\fakepath\file". I think that it is a browser issue (I'm using Chrome), but before changing the browser settings, I wonder if there is any way to do the same procedure without having this error. Is there any javascript library to perform this procedure correctly? How can we fix this error code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showFileName() {
   var fil = document.getElementById("myFile");
   alert(fil.value);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frmMain" name="frmMain">
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile"/>
    <a href="#" onclick="showFileName()">Show Name</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As always, thank you very much for the help. :)

Comment: This isn't a bug, it's a security "feature".

Comment: Is there a way around this feature? Another way to save the path of a file that does not have this problem?

Comment: if you really want this, you'll have to use _Java_ or _Flash_ instead of the `<input type="file" />`.

Comment: The problem is that I can not use other technologies like java or flash. I can only use html5, css and javascript